# Can you use ng-if for display size

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to use ng-if to very simply not load an element for smaller screen sizes?

Comment: Seems like a [CSS media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) would be simpler.

Comment: If you really need to, you can you the [`$window` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window) to get the actual window and ng-if from there.

Comment: I'm also using bootstrap, so hiding things is easy. I was just thinking since ng-if doesn't just hide items but excludes them from the DOM it would save on mobile load times.

Comment: How do you use the $window service?

Answer (score 11):

You can use [angular-match-media](https://github.com/jacopotarantino/angular-match-media) for that.

In your controller you can create variables that correspond to screen sizes. For example add the following to your controller:

```
// Using static method `is`
angular.module('myApp', ['matchMedia'])
.controller('mainController', ['screenSize', function(screenSize) {
  $scope.isScreenSize = screenSize.is;
}]);
```

Then in your HTML you can show or hide content using ngIf or similar directives that take an Angular expression:

```
<img ng-if="isScreenSize('md, lg')" ng-src='http://example.com/path/to/giant/image.jpg'>
```

This particular example is great for only loading large, unnecessary images on desktop computers.

Note: It's important if you plan on using `screensize.is()` in directives to assign its return value to a scoped variable. If you don't, it will only be evaluated once and will not update if the window is resized or if a mobile device is turned sideways.

Comment: Nice! I'd even go one step further and making your own version of this plugin for maximum control. Could even be a directive usable in a similar way that bootstrap adds hidden-sm classes. i.e hide-if-mobile, show-if-iphone hide-if-desktop etc etc

Answer (score 6):

An alternative to ng-if, is if you are using Angular Material for your layout they provide directives hide and show to control visibility of elements based on screen size.

For example:

```
<div hide-gt-sm>You'll only see me on small screens</div>
<div show-gt-lg>You'll only see me on big screens</div>
```

Docs:

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/options

Comment: That solution only hide the element (display:none). He want to remove from the DOM, the best solution for me was using angular-match-media.